# Can I run Nuxt 3 without using <script setup>?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

Is it possible to migrate a Nuxt 2 application to Nuxt 3 and keep the JavaScript I execute in the pages between pure `<script>` tags, instead of updating them to the `<script setup>` tag?

If not, what are the changes I should make to my code? Basically: what are the main differences between these two?

Comment: You could still use traditional <script> no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Nuxt 3 still supports the option api, and you can just use

```html
<script>
export default {
    // your code
}
</script>
```